# How to keep a button at the end of the table

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to keep the button appended at the end of the table.

At the moment it works great as long as I don't click the **'X'** of last `<tr`> : here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amigoo/1n4f3sno/1/)

This is the function which appends the button:

```
function del() {

    var last_tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].lastChild;

    if (last_tr.lastChild.children.length != 1) {
        var t = document.createElement("td");
        t.innerHTML = "<button onclick=\"addElements(); this.remove(this);\">+</button>";
        last_tr.appendChild(t)
    }
}
```

Any guess what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you're deleting the button. Either add it *back* or remove it from the row. :)

Comment: Yes I am adding it back. Only time it doesn't add back is the time when 'x' from the `last row` is clicked and that's the problem. Please have a look into fiddle. @CaseyFalk

Comment: I *did* look at your fiddle, @FaisalAshfaq; I meant add it back *after* it gets deleted (which is the lazy way to go). Just remove it from the row of elements that gets deleted.

Comment: Well that's an easy choice! ;) but I don't want it to remove from row. The key is- how can I determine when the 'x' from the `last row` was clicked? So that I could place that inside `if` condition.

Comment: The issue is not that the last row is clicked, but that that's the row with the button. The addback is simply failing.

Comment: Hmm you're right @isherwood. So Is there only way to remove this btn from the row as CaseyFalk suggested ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing the button, you can simply hide it and display only the last rows button using the following CSS:

```
tr:last-child button{
 display:inline !important;
}
```

In JS, change the following

```
this.remove(this);
```

to

```
this.style.display='none';
```

You can avoid unnecessary `DOM` manipulation as well.

(*If there is only one row, it'll be the last child as well*)

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/1n4f3sno/4/)

Comment: Nice. Sometimes just hiding things is better than managing their actual existence.

Comment: What an inspiration! Worked like a charm.
+1 for thinking out of the box. Thanks Tilwin

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the order of the function calls on the delete button:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/1n4f3sno/3/

```
onclick=\" this.parentNode.parentNode.remove(this); del();\"
```

You're calculating the new last row before you remove the old last row. There's still a problem if you only have one row left, but I'm sure you can work that out.

Also, you can eliminate the need for all those escape characters if you always use single quotes (apostrophes) for JS and double quotes for HTML.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! +1 for making fix such simple. I was at verge of marking your answer as accepted but in the meantime I found Tilwin's answer more useful. Thanks again.